# Working with SessionScope, TransactionScope, ActiveRecord, C# and Trigger in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, nhibernate, activerecord, triggers

I'm having problems the in method create that is within a transaction and session Scope, because the table in the database has a trigger. Any suggestion?

This is the error I get:

> An error occurred when trying to dispose the transaction
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Exception: An error occurred when trying to dispose the transaction

Obs.

If I remove the trigger, there is no error.

Code:

```
using (var session = new SessionScope())
{
   try
   {
      using (Transaction = new TransactionScope(TransactionMode.New,  OnDispose.Commit))
      {
        class.Create();
      }
      Transaction.VoteCommit();
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      Transaction.VoteRollBack();
      throw new Exception(ex.Message);
   }
}
```

Comment: If the trigger seems to be the problem, you should post the **trigger code** !

Comment: > ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[CleanupTableAuthTemp] ON [dbo].[USERS] INSTEAD OF
> INSERT AS BEGIN   DECLARE _ID INT; SET _UID = USERS.SCOPE_IDENTITY();
> DELETE USERSTEMP WHERE [LOGIN] = _UID; END

Comment: Please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Comment: The error was in trigger ... was using INSTEAD OF and not AFTER. very bad my compilation!

Thanks & regards.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem was the position of the using statement:

```
using (var session = new SessionScope())
{
    using (Transaction = new TransactionScope(TransactionMode.New,  OnDispose.Commit))
    {
        try
        {
            class.Create();
            Transaction.VoteCommit();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Transaction.VoteRollBack();
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

you dispose Transaction before you can call Commit or Rollback.

Comment: The transaction is null before calling....

I think the problem is with the mapping between the nhibernate, activerecord .... when a table is linked to a trigger. Soon ... within a transaction happens the exception mentioned.

Comment: recalling that the activerecord being initialized this way:

ActiveRecordStarter.Initialize (asms, source);